# Text replacements are now stored in your iCloud account; what else is there?

Tags: keyboard, icloud

I just discovered that [text replacements are stored in the iCloud account](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/mac#:%7E:text=Tip%3A%20You%20can%20use%20iCloud,using%20the%20same%20Apple%20ID.) now.

Is there a list of everything that's stored there?

Are they stored in the iCloud Drive or some magic inaccessible place?

Comment: You have misinterpreted the support note. They are not stored in iCloud, they are synchronised between devices using iCloud, **if** you enable iCloud Drive. They are still very much on your device. As to being magically inaccessible, they will be in a plist or similar in your ~/Library. They're not meant to be accessible except via the proper interface, but Apple isn't trying to wilfully hide things.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths CloudKit records are not user inspectable and would certainly qualify as a "magic inaccessible place" in contrast to iCloud Drive.

Comment: Do we have any clue where CloudKit is stored?